# lvalue required as left operand of assignment (while loop)

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
while (CMMC%a=!0 && CMMC%b=!0){
    cout << CMMC;
    CMMC++;
```

Hi guys!

I am new to C++ and I am trying to learn but I am starting with the basics. I have an error on the above while condition. The logic is ... While CMMC divided by a and b is not 0 then CMMC adds 1 and then the CMMC is checked again. I know it is silly, but I am just starting with C++ and I cannot find the solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

Inequality operator is `!=`, but not `=!`

Comment: And I would extend it to say that what you are actually doing with the reverse is attempting to set `CMMC` equal to the value `!0`.

Comment: and the error is because you try to assign `!0` to the result of modulus operator, which is a rvalue